# VBA: Macro to divide range by a million

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in an Excel sheet with hardcoded values, in millions. How can I write a VBA macro to divide a selected range by a million?

Best regards

Comment: Do it manually using the Macro Recorder and it will show you a way to code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No macro needed.

- Write 1,000,000 in one cell
- Copy that cell
- Select the range with hard-coded values
- `Paste Special` and select `Divide`
- `OK`

[image]

Comment: In my years of using Excel, I have always ignored Paste Special aside from using it to Paste as Values. This is cool functionality, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

No loop needed

```
Sub MyDivide
    Selection.Value = Selection.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(" & Selection.address & "/1000000,)")
End Sub
```

Just select the cell you want and run the sub.

Comment: Nice for a single cell, or for a standard rectangle of cells, but not very friendly for a non-contiguous range.  (Appears to clear cells if it isn't a contiguous range selected, I assume due to the `,` in the `Selection.Address` being incorrectly interpreted.)

Comment: That is correct,  It needs to be contiguous. @YowE3K

Answer (score 3):

For something as simple as this, I would write a formula in an area near the range (underneath if a row, beside if a column, etc.) and copy/paste as values and replace the original area.

If you really want to make a macro for this, you can assign a range to a variable, including the selected range. From there, loop through each cell in the range and replace value with the desired value (something like this):

```
Dim cell as Object

For Each cell in Selection
    cell.value = cell.value / 1000000
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom number format to make cells **look** like they were divided by a million while retaining the true raw underlying values.

```
sub meh()
    selection.numberformat = "0,,\M"
end sub
```

I've added a *M* as a unit suffix.